# Get a object values from a word

Tags: javascript, object

Let's say I have this objects in a JS file:

```
const persons = [
    {
        name: 'John Doe',
        picture: 'https://images.google.com',
        year: '1971'
    },
    {
        name: 'Peter Doe',
        picture: 'https://images.google.com',
        year: '1981'
    }]
```

How do I get a entire object list (name, picture and year) using just name as keyword? Like if the name is John Doe it gets only John Doe's name, picture and year?

Comment: Use `.find()` method: `persons.find(obj => obj.name == searchedName);`. Note that this method will only find the first occurence of any object whose name matches the searched name. If you want to find all the objects with a particular name, you can use `.filter()` method.

Comment: how about using ```.filter()``` method? it will return the array of filtered result : ```persons.filter(item => item.name === 'John Doe')```